# Username increment by 1 if already exist in mssql 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Create table  TEMP_USER
( 
USERNAME  nvarchar(50) ,
ID  int,
Phone nvarchar(30)
);
```

IF the user name already exist in temp_user  it should incement by 1 while inserting through SP.
Example  : RAM .Narayan  if anyone trying to insert  again ram.narayan it should insert as ram.narayan1 next time anyone trying to insert  ram.narayan it should insert ram.narayan2 ..How to do this in MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following (untested, but it should give you a good start). It assumes the variables `@username`, `@id`, and `@phone` are already declared or passed as parameters.

```
DECLARE @curr_uname nvarchar(50) = @username
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEMP_USER WHERE USERNAME = @curr_uname)
BEGIN
    SET @i += 1
    SET @curr_uname = @username + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(7))
END

INSERT INTO TEMP_USER (USERNAME, ID, Phone)
VALUES (@curr_uname, @id, @phone)
```

Comment: 2nd insert fails (ram.narain2)

Comment: ram.narayan ram narayan 1 22542280
ram.narayan1 ram narayan 1 22542280
ram.narayan1 ram narayan 1 22542280
ram.narayan1 ram narayan 1 22542280
ram.narayan1 ram narayan 1 22542280